# Python - Multiple OR statements, which one was triggered?

Tags: python

So, I have a simple Django project, where data is coming from external API.
Also, there is function that calls the api for already stored object in db and checks if values coming from API are different from model's.

If so, then there is an update to local model scheduled.

I would like to implement some sort of Logs mechanic for those updates to see, what was actually updated on local objects.

Right now values are compared by multiple OR statements:

```
if ((str(image.shoper_gfx_id) != str(shoper_gfx_id))
   or (str(image.shoper_product_id) != str(shoper_product_id))
   or (str(image.shoper_main) != str(shoper_main))
   or (str(image.shoper_order) != str(shoper_order))
   or (str(image.shoper_image_name) != str(shoper_image_name))
   or (str(image.shoper_unic) != str(shoper_unic))
   or (str(image.shoper_hidden) != str(shoper_hidden))
   or (str(image.shoper_extension) != str(shoper_extension))
):
```

So, my main question is : **Can I somehow find which of this OR statements was triggered to store it in Log model for instance?**

Thank You very much.

Comment: Split it in to multiple `if...elif` statements, one per `or` statement. This will allow you to know which one it was for sure. **Edit:** the _first_ one will be known using `if...elif`. Using `if...if...if...` approach will allow you to do something with each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be done in a cleaner way. My approach would be to iterate through them and then see which one(s) are false. Like so:

```
attrs = ["shoper_gfx_id", "shoper_product_id",
    "shoper_main","shoper_order","shoper_image_name",
    "shoper_unic","shoper_hidden","shoper_extension"]
or_statements_triggered = []
full_or_statement = True
for attr in attrs:
    if image.getattr(attr) != attr:
        full_or_statement = False
        or_statements_triggered.append(attr)

if full_or_statement:
    pass # do what you want to do here...
```

Then you have a list of items which were false in the `or_statements_triggered` variable, and you can use the `full_or_statement` bool to do what you originally wanted to do in your `or` statement

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's impossible since each condition is evaluated, and we can only get the result.

However, there's a simpler way to do this by store your condition in a list like this:

```
# change the condition based on yours
conditions = [0>1, 9<10, 2==1]
for i, state in enumerate(conditions):
  if state == True:
    print("statement " + str(i) +" is True")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using python3.8 or higher, you can do:

```
if ((str(image.shoper_gfx_id) != str(shoper_gfx_id))
   or (str(image.shoper_product_id) != str(shoper_product_id))
   or (str(image.shoper_main) != str(shoper_main))
   or (str(image.shoper_order) != str(shoper_order))
   or (str(image.shoper_image_name) != str(shoper_image_name))
   or (str(image.shoper_unic) != str(shoper_unic))
   or (str(image.shoper_hidden) != str(shoper_hidden))
   or (str(image.shoper_extension) != str(shoper_extension))
):
    print(f"""{str(image.shoper_gfx_id) != str(shoper_gfx_id) =}
   {str(image.shoper_product_id) != str(shoper_product_id) =}
   {str(image.shoper_main) != str(shoper_main) =}
   {str(image.shoper_order) != str(shoper_order) =}
   {str(image.shoper_image_name) != str(shoper_image_name) =}
   {str(image.shoper_unic) != str(shoper_unic) =}
   {str(image.shoper_hidden) != str(shoper_hidden) =}
   {str(image.shoper_extension) != str(shoper_extension) =}""")
```